# How to collide using Rect in Pygame for Platformers game

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making this platformers game but I am stuck in this colliding part for some time now.

```
playerimg = pygame.image.load("imgs\\player.png")
px = 50
py = 0

def player(x,y):
    win.blit(playerimg, (px, py))

rect = pygame.Rect(px,py,playerimg.get_width(),playerimg.get_height())

objectRect = pygame.Rect(100,50,100,50)

pleft = False
pright = False
jumping = 0

running = True
while running:

    win.fill((122, 245, 253))

    if py+73 > 450:
        jumping= -jumping
    else:
        jumping += 0.2
    py += jumping
    if pleft == True:
        px -= 4
    if pright == True:
        px += 4
    rect.x = px
    rect.y = py
    objectRect.x = 200
    objectRect.y = 200

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerimg = pygame.image.load("imgs\\playerMirror.png")
                pleft = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerimg = pygame.image.load("imgs\\player.png")
                pright = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pleft = False
                pright = False

    player(px, py)
    base(bx, by)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), objectRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I couldn't get it right.

Comment: Can you explain what objects do you want to collide and what is wrong with current behavior

Comment: first use `print()` to see values in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"`. OR learn how to use real debuger.

Comment: `objectRect.colliderect( rect )` ? `rect.colliderect(objectRect)` ?

Comment: instead of `px`, `py` you can use always `rect` and `win.blit(playerimg, rect)`

Comment: BTW: `rect = playerimg.get_rect(x=px, y=py)`

Answer (score 0):

To check collision you can do

```
if player_rect.colliderect(object_rect):
```

but it doesn't inform on which side player collides with object - left, right, top, bottom. You have to check in which direction player moves - if it move left then probably it collide on right size, etc.

```
if player_rect.colliderect(object_rect):
    if jumping < 0:
        player_rect.top = object_rect.bottom
    else:
        player_rect.bottom = object_rect.top
```

After moving top/bottom and checking collision top/bottom you should move left/right and check collision left/right. Don't move at once in both directions top/bottom and left/right because then you can't recognize on which side you collided.

---

Minimal working code which everyone can run (because it uses `Surfaces` instead of images)

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# ---

#player_image_1 = pygame.image.load("imgs\\player.png")
#player_image_2 = pygame.image.load("imgs\\playerMirror.png")
player_image_1 = pygame.surface.Surface((50, 50))
player_image_1.fill((255,0,0))
player_image_2 = pygame.surface.Surface((50, 50))
player_image_2.fill((0,255,0))

player_image = player_image_1 
player_rect = player_image.get_rect(x=50, y=0)

object_rect = pygame.Rect(100, 50, 100, 50)
object_rect.x = 200
object_rect.y = 200

pleft = False
pright = False
jumping = 0

# --- main loop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:

    # --- events ---
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player_image = player_image_2
                pleft = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_image = player_image_1
                pright = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pleft = False
                pright = False

    # --- updates (without draws) ---
    
    # move top/bottom
    
    if player_rect.y+73 > 450:
        jumping= -jumping
    else:
        jumping += 0.2
        
    player_rect.y += jumping

    # check collision top/bottom
    
    if player_rect.colliderect(object_rect):
        if jumping < 0:
            player_rect.top = object_rect.bottom
        else:
            player_rect.bottom = object_rect.top

    # move left/right
    
    speed_x = 0    
    if pleft:
        speed_x = -4
    if pright:
        speed_x = +4
    
    player_rect.x += speed_x

    # check collision left/right

    if player_rect.colliderect(object_rect):
        if speed_x < 0:
            player_rect.left = object_rect.right
        elif speed_x > 0:
            player_rect.right = object_rect.left
            
    # --- draws (without updates) ---

    win.fill((122, 245, 253))
    win.blit(player_image, player_rect)
    #base(bx, by)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), object_rect)
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```